# Woocommerce como cambiar descripción de la variación sin no hay stock

Tags: woocommerce

Necesito algo muy simple pero no se como implementarlo. Probe con el plugin "Custom Stock Status" pero no me muestra nada.
Quiero algo incluso más sencillo. En la plantilla de Woocommerce "variation.php" tenemos la siguiente línea:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
```

Lo que quiero es cambiar esa descripción a "Sin stock" cuando éste sea cero. He probado con un IF para cambiar el valor pero no consigo nada.

¿Alguien me puede indicar como cambiar esta variable de forma dinámica?

Gracias

Comment: A lo mejor esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés te puede ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107321/change-woocommerce-in-stock-out-stock-text

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado pero no me muestra nada. Sale siempre el texto que tenga en el campo descripción.

Comment: Creo que esa función es para las descripciones de productos simples, yo busco cambiar las variaciones de un producto que no tengan stock. Para que al hacer clic, muestre el mensaje de "sin stock" solo en las que no tenga.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de muchas vueltas he encontrado una solución bastante sencilla. La clave estaba en el archivo variable.php que genera el formulario de las variaciones. Justo antes del formulario hay que añadir un bucle que recorra las mismas comprobando si hay stock o no. Exactamente después de este ***action***:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

Yo he usado el campo "max_qty" para evaluar cada variación:

```
foreach( $available_variations as $i => $variation ) {
//Compruebo la cantidad máxima (cuando no hay stock está vacía)
if ($variation['max_qty'] > 0 ) {       
    $texto = '<p>¡Recíbelo mañana!</p>';
} else {
    $texto = '<p>Sin Existencias</p>';
}
//Actualizo el campo con el nuevo valor
$available_variations[$i]['variation_description'] = $texto;}
```

¡IMPORTANTE! El archivo "variable.php" se encuentra en "plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart" pero si utilizáis plugin o theme child que lo pisen, tendréis que añadir la modificación en ellos.

Espero que os sirva.

Comment: He mejorada esta función haciendo uso del filtro "woocommerce_available_variation". Así seguirá funcionando aunque cambie el archivo variable.php